# How to remove tag from a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string i.e

```
String test = "<p> My company is best in world. I love my company </p>";
```

I have to remove both the tags `<p>` and `</p>`.
I tried using

```
String replacingPtag = test.replaceAll("<p>", "");
String r1 = replacingPtag.replaceAll("</p>", "");
```

This code removed the `<p>` tag but not `</p>`.

How can I remove both forms of the tag?

Comment: Most probaly you are printing `replacingPtag` you have to print `r1` [check](http://ideone.com/lbUJnI)

Comment: Are you sure?  The code that you've exhibited works fine for me - it replaces both tags.

Comment: Your code is correct. You must be printing replacingPtag to console.

Comment: Your code works just fine. The regex suggested by Evgeniy works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
String res = test.replaceAll("</?p>", "");
```